# Which functions could be discussed in a calculus course?

Tags: calculus, functions, education

In a typical calculus course, students are exposed to many functions. Some have their origin in a field of study, while others are simply combinations of polynomials, trig functions, exponentials, and logs that are put together simply to have an interesting chain/power rule etc.

My question is this: Do you know of any functions that are common (or essential) in a field (Math/Physics/Chemistry/Biology/Engineering) that are not commonly discussed in calculus texts--or perhaps are not done justice in calculus texts?

Comment: You mean some functions that have useful applications in experimental fields?

Comment: Sure - I'd be interested in any function that is not typically found (or done justice) in a (standard) calculus course, that could/should be studied in a calculus course.